# Linux - get text from second tab

Tags: linux, bash, text

Suppose that we have file like this:

> sometext11    sometext12    sometext13
>   sometext21    sometext22    sometext23

Texts are separated by tabs and we know sometext from column 1 but want to get text from column 2.
I know I can get line by:

```
grep 'sometext11' file.txt
```

How to get text from second column?
Maybe some tool with option -t [column nr]?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

awk:

```
awk '{print $2}' file.txt
```

cut:

```
cut -f2 file.txt
```

bash:

```
while read -a A; do echo ${A[1]}; done < file.txt
```

perl:

```
perl -lane 'print $F[1]' file.txt
```

If you know the string you are grepping for, you can use `grep`:

```
grep -o 'sometext12' file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{print $2}' < yourfile
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cut](http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-columns-cut.html) command

```
cut -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `grep`:

```
awk '/sometext11/ {print $2}' file.txt
```

or you can do it all in `grep` if yours supports Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE), such as GNU or OS X `grep`:

```
grep -Po '(?<=sometext11\t).*?(?=\t.*)' file.txt
```